# New row in groovy script from grid [PBCS oracle]

Tags: groovy, grid

I need to add a new column to filter the part text of the 'rowmbr1' and place in the new column.

Example:

Value of rowmbr1 is "Sales staff" or "Marketing staff"

in the output csv I need a new column next to rowmbr1 with only text "Sales" or "Marketing"

**My script without new column:**

```
def povDims = [ Povdim1, povdim2]
def povMbrs = [['Povmbr1'], ['povmbr2']]
def colDims =  ['coldim'] 
def colMbrs = [ ['coldim1','coldim2'] 
def rowDims = ['rowdim']
def rowMbrs = [ ['rowmbr1']]

 
Cube cube = operation.application.getCube("Plan")
DataGridDefinitionBuilder builder = cube.dataGridDefinitionBuilder()
builder.setSuppressMissingBlocks(true)
builder.setSuppressMissingRows(true)
builder.addPov(povDims, povMbrs)
builder.addColumn(colDims, colMbrs)
builder.addRow(rowDims, rowMbrs)


DataGridDefinition gridDefinition = builder.build()

cube.loadGrid(gridDefinition, false).withCloseable {
grid ->

  //def filteredRows = grid.rows.findAll{it.data.findAll{it.name() == 'Territory'}}

    operation.exportDataToFile(grid, 'fullGridExport.csv')
    }
```

your help is greatly appreciated.

Example:

Value of rowmbr1 is "Sales staff" or "Marketing staff"

in the output csv I need a new column next to rowmbr1 with only text "Sales" or "Marketing"

I am unable to create the new column before exporting the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a EssBase or EPM expert, but you'll need to create a column that gets it's value from a dynamic expression.  So something like the following:

```
String memberFunc = """StrToMbr( CASE [rowdim].CurrentMember
   WHEN [rowdim].[Sales staff] THEN "Sales"
   WHEN [rowdim].[Marketing staff] THEN "Marketing"
   ELSE "" 
)"""

Dimension members = operation.application.getDimension("Measures")
members.saveMember(Member: memberFunc, Name: "Departments" )

def rowDims = [ '[Measures].[Departments]' ]
```

In MDX I think it's more straightforward:

```
with member [Measures].[Departments] as
  StrToMbr( CASE [rowdim].CurrentMember
     WHEN [rowdim].[Sales staff] THEN "Sales"
     WHEN [rowdim].[Marketing staff] THEN "Marketing"
     ELSE "" 
  )
  select [column1].Members on Columns
         [Measures].[Departments] on Rows
  where
       [PovDim1].[Member1], [PovDim2].[Member2], ...
```

The Groovy API doesn't really give a lot of detail on how to translate from MDX into the API, but I gave it my best.